# How to debug Javascript run by a different application (Resco MobileCRM) via "Attach" in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some Javascript code, that is run in an internal browser in the application Resco MobileCRM. I can use Visual Studio to attach to the process and debug the script code. How can I achieve this with Visual Studio Code?
I tried ".NET Core Attach", that does attach to the process, but does not debug the script code.

Regards

Sven